# "Admission free" for master program

Tags: graduate-admissions, germany

I'm aiming to apply for a MA in Germany and in the description for my programme of choice it says:

> The study course is *admission free*.

I'm a bit unsure of what this could mean, any German student could clarify if this means that meeting the criteria is enough for admission or something else?

**How to apply section**

> Most important points
>
> The study course is admission free. Application
> for beginning students is possible in summer semester.
>
> First day of application: December 15th 2017
>
> Application deadline: March 31st 2018
>
> Special admission requirements: Bachelor's
> degree or equivalent qualification in Philosophy or in a closely
> related field worth at least 60 credit points.
>
> Admission requirements: A very good command of German is required.

**Application/admission procedure section**

> This is an open admissions degree course, and applications are
> accepted for both the winter and summer semesters. Please note For
> open-admission Master's degree programmes it is strongly recommended
> to submit their applications as early as possible before 15 July for
> the winter semester. If the supporting documents are submitted after
> these dates but before the standard application deadlines, your
> application can only be processed at the start of the lecture period
> in the new semester.

Comment: I think you should provide more of the information as this is most probably context specific and is part of a section explaining  their criteria.

Comment: I'll copy-paste the _how to apply_ section below:

**Most important points**

    The study course is _admission free._
    Application for **beginning students** is possible in **summer semester**.
    First day of application: December 15th 2017
    Application deadline: March 31st 2018
    Application: Click here.

**Special admission requirements**

Bachelor's degree or equivalent qualification in Philosophy or in a closely related field worth at least 60 credit points.

**Admission requirements**

A very good command of German is required.

Comment: and here's the **Aplication/admission procedure** section:
This is an open admissions degree course, and applications are accepted for both the winter and summer semesters.

Please note
For open-admission Master's degree programmes it is strongly recommended to submit their applications as early as possible before 15 July for the winter semester. If the supporting documents are submitted after these dates but before the standard application deadlines, your application can only be processed at the start of the lecture period in the new semester.

Comment: Have you checked the German version of the description? Maybe it's a mistranslation and it will become clear once you check the original version. (I assume you know *some* German at least, or you wouldn't apply to a program where "a very good command of German is required").

Comment: As one other comment hints, it may be possible that your german may not be good enough for this course if you had to ask...

Comment: I think it's a bit ironic that a department that translates *zulassungsfrei* so poorly is being picky on applicants' foreign language proficiency.

Comment: It's good English, just suboptimal punctuation.  *"admission: free"* means "free admission, no payment" written down in a fact sheet style; *"admission-free"* means lack of admission. The former is pronounced clearly as two words.

Comment: @AlexVWyn It would be better if you can edit those extra details into the question: it would be easier to read, you can better preserve the original layout, and comments are not regarded as permanent.

Comment: @CapeCode What's ironic about that? The german language proficiency is required to attend the course. The english language version of the page is simply there as a matter of convenience, there is no expectation that whoever is maintaining that side should have a very good command of the english language.

Comment: @Cubic the least amount of due diligence for the person who made that website is to have it proofread.

Comment: @Kaz neither of these make much sense in that context. Even Google Translate does a better job and returns “open admission”.

Comment: If you could post the German version someone here could give you the correct translation.

Answer (score 40):

This is most likely a very confusing translation of "zulassungsfrei", as opposed to "zulassungsbeschränkt";
the former meaning that there are no special restrictions placed on who will be admitted, you just need to satisfy the basic requirements for being allowed to enroll. In case of a Master's degree, that would probably be a relevant Bachelor's degree.

"Zulassungsbeschränkt", on the other hand, means that there will be some selection procedure because the number of spots is limited. Usually selection is by grades.

Comment: The first concept is commonly known as "open enrollment" in the USA. This means that there is no competitive process - anyone who fulfills the baseline criteria may enroll. Most "community colleges" in the USA are Open Enrollment, with the basic criteria being a high school diploma or equivalent.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Yes, that is indeed the same concept. The obvious difference being that it is a lot more common in Germany than in the US in many fields. (For example most CS Bachelor programs in Germany are "zulassungsfrei".)

Answer (score 36):

The phrase *admission free* certainly is an attempt to translate the German *zulassungsfrei*.

*Zulassungsfrei* means that everyone satisfying the basic requirements can enroll in the course.

Sometimes it means that it is not necessary to apply for admission at all, and one can directly move to the enrollment step. **However**, this varies on a university by university basis, so do not rely on this unless you have verified that it is applicable to your university. Based on the extra info given by the OP, it does not apply in their case.

In the other cases, one still applies for admission, but this is a pure formal check of requirements.

Comment: Well, looks like I was 16 seconds too late.

Comment: Both good answers anyway.